# Error in boost format

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, boost-format

When I try to compile in cygwin there are problem like this:

> fatal error: boost/format.hpp: No such file or directory  #include
>   <boost/format.hpp>

How I fix this problem, someone please help me...

Comment: Did you install Boost?

Comment: Downvoted for a lack of minimal research effort

Comment: @Wintermute He might not have installed it, or he simply might not have told the compiler about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this error for 2 reasons:

1. You forgot to add `#include <boost/format.hpp>` in your file.
2. You don't have [boost](http://www.boost.org/users/download/) installed. Installation guide [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html).

Comment: Without the `#include`, he won't get an error about the compiler not finding the include.  And even if boost has been installed, he also has to tell the compiler about it.  How he does that, of course, depends on the compiler: for most compilers, adding a `-I` option does the trick; with Visual Studios, you need to add an `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` (or something similar) to the project file.

Comment: How to link boost to your project.

1 . Create a new project in Visual Studio
2. Go to Project -> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories and add boost/stage/lib directory to it. (e.g.: E:\ boost_1_57_0\stage\lib )
3. Go to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories and add boost directory to it.

Now you will be able to build your project without any errors !

Comment: He said he was trying to compile in CygWin.  So fiddling with project files won't help; he needs to add the relevant flags to his makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to erase `/format.hpp` from `<boost/format.hpp>`, then add "/", i.e., `<boost/>`, then start typing "form" and select `format.hpp` from the drop-down list.

It looks like this will force Visual Studio to find the necessary dependencies again, and the error has disappeared for me.

[image: screenshot]